# Uptime is not correct

Tags: uptime

Weird. When I ask the command line for the uptime of my device, today (February 1, 2024) I get the answer that is:

```
$ uptime -s
2024-01-29 17:56:53
```

This date is still in the future!

Comment: We have been in 2024 for a month now, ICYMI.

Comment: In which universe is 2024-01-29 the future??? 

Comment: ... I'm having a very hard time trying to make sense of that and I have a feeling it's not my understanding :-)

Answer (score 3):

uptime -s means "up since ..."

So it seems that your system has been up since 2024-01-29 17:56:53 - which is January 29 2024 - a couple of days ago today.

Comment: Yes. But when I executed the command, it was 26/1/2024

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of 'date' and 'uptime -s' ... ?

Comment: @JormaHytonen then why would you say: "today (February 1, 2024) I get the answer..."?